# Javascript automaticaly adds <tbody> to appended string

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with my HTML and Javascript code. I want to generate a grid that fits in the screen width.

There are two issues with my code when I run it in my browser:

The first issue is that the browser adds `<tbody></tbody>` to every string I append to the table element.

The next issue is that for some reason, the browser doesn't bother to execute the `setInterval(AnimateGrid(cellArray), 1000);` command I have at the end, it only colors 2 cells of the table and then stops, but it is supposed to infinitely keep coloring the table.

Can someone point out to me what am I doing wrong in my code? I know my code isn't optimised and I'm just a beginner. There's no need to help me optimize it, but I'd just like to know why it doesn't do what I described above.

So far I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="AnimateAll()" id="body">
  <center>
    <table id="table">
    </table>
  </center>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function generateTable() {
      var table = document.getElementById("table");
      /* Calculate how many cells fit in the screen width */
      var bodywidth = window.outerWidth;
      //each cell is 22px in width (stylesheet), so we devide the screenwidth in 22.
      var cellamountunrounded = bodywidth / 22;
      //round the number downwards
      var cellamount = Math.floor(cellamountunrounded); //this is the amount of cells in one row
      /* Generate a table that has that amount of cells on-screen with correct Id's */
      /* Table has 3 rows */
      table.innerHTML += "<tr>";
      for (var i = 1; i <= cellamount; i++) {
        table.innerHTML += "<td id=" + i + "></td>";
      }
      table.innerHTML += "</tr><tr>";
      for (var i = cellamount + 1; i <= cellamount * 2; i++) {
        table.innerHTML += "<td id=" + i + "></td>";
      }
      table.innerHTML += "</tr><tr>";
      for (var i = 2 * cellamount; i <= cellamount * 3; i++) {
        table.innerHTML += "<td id=" + i + "></td>";
      }
      table.innerHTML += "</tr>";


      /* Make this function return the amount of cells */
      return cellamount * 3;
    }

    function numberToArray(Number) {

      /* Example: 5=>['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']*/
      var Array = [];

      for (var i = 1; i <= Number; i++) {
        Array.push(i);
      }
      /* Make this function return an Array */
      return Array;
    }


    function RandomFromArray(Array) {
      var myArray = Array;
      var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
      return rand;
    }


    function AnimateGrid(Array) {
      //var cellArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33'];
      var cellArray = Array;
      var colorArray = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Orange', 'Black', 'Purple', 'Brown'];
      document.getElementById(RandomFromArray(cellArray)).style.backgroundColor = RandomFromArray(colorArray);
      document.getElementById(RandomFromArray(cellArray)).style.backgroundColor = RandomFromArray(colorArray);
    }

    function AnimateAll() {

      var cells = generateTable();
      var cellArray = numberToArray(cells);

      setInterval(AnimateGrid(cellArray), 1000);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` doesn't "write" to the document, it replaces the current content with new, valid content, where all the elements have their ending tas too. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: You should avoid using global object names like `Array` and `Number` as variables. In addition to not being able to construct a table in fragments like this, [you're thrashing the hell out the DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing). Instead, build your table in memory and then inject to the DOM once complete.

Comment: Also, read about [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval): it takes a _function_, but you are passing `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `innerHTML`.

Browser will attempt to clean up your "broken" html because it doesn't know your entering lines in sequence.

build a string with all html and then append it to table

something like this:

```
let html = ''; 
html += "<tr>";
for (var i = 1; i <= cellamount; i++) {
   html += "<td id="+i+"></td>";
 }
html += "</tr><tr>";
 for (var i = cellamount + 1; i <= cellamount * 2; i++) {
 html += "<td id="+i+"></td>";
 }
html += "</tr><tr>";
 for (var i = 2 * cellamount; i <= cellamount * 3; i++) {
 html += "<td id="+i+"></td>";
 }
html += "</tr>";


// and then add the string to HTML
// `.append()` inside your table
table.appendChild(html)


return cellamount * 3;
}
```

**update**

for your second issue

instead of this

`setInterval(AnimateGrid(cellArray), 1000);`

try this

`setInterval(function() {AnimateGrid(cellArray)}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

For the tbody issue, I recommend adding your tbody maunually and appending to that.

```
<table>
  <tbody id="table">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

For your issue with setInterval, see if there's an error in the console. It should list all of the places where things went wrong. If there is no error don't forget the utility of console.log(). You can use it to place points in your code to see if it's being executed. This will let you pinpoint the exact line that's causing problems.

Comment: Console doesn't print any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `table.innerHTML +=` constructions with buffer. Like

```
let tableContent = "";
tableContent += "<tr>";
// fill all the data
table.innerHTML = tableContent;
```

It might fix both the problems